# Write platform specific code in crossplatform xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I tried to use the Xamarin.Android namespace in my crossplatform Xamarin project. When i now build the .iOS Project, i get the notification, that this namespace is, obviously, not existing for iOS.

**How can i write platform specific Code, where i use platform specific libraries ?**

I already checked the Microsoft Docs but i did not find any information that could solve my problem.

PS: This is my first contribution to Stack Overflow, so feel free to ask for more detailed information.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. You can use DependencyService or Custom Renderer. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "*I already checked the Microsoft Docs but i did not find any information that could solve my problem*" - there are many examples of this in official documentation and oodles of examples online, what part don't you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Above is a link to DependencyService documentation. DependencyService allows you as a developer to call platform-specific code from your Xamarin.Forms shared code.

Comment: Glad I could help you :)