# android or IOS - do device specific stuff

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

So simply put I want to record audio from a mic on either Android or IOS phones once a record button is pressed from XAML. Obviously, the Android specific code will live under Android project head and IOS in the IOS project head (see image). The main problem is audio stuff is different for each device type, so i cant use shared code for that. So, is there a way I can signal from pressing the buttons in the XAML, which is kept under its own project head (it use shared code), to the currently used device either Android or IOS?

e.g. button is clicked to start recording -> XAML notifies my cs file under the shared code that it wants to start recording and sends out some kind of signal or calls the code, to the current device type e.g android or IOS ->  that device then starts recording from its cs code

Hope this makes sense?

[top is the shared code, and the other two are self explanatory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7qa0.png)

Comment: I may have just found the solution to my own problem if someone could confirm https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Yes, Use DependencyService. [Write platform specific code in crossplatform xamarin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614420/write-platform-specific-code-in-crossplatform-xamarin-project)